# Ajax call for OGRE converter

Tags: javascript, ajax, shapefile

I am trying to use OGRE online converter to convert shape-files to different format, referring https://ogre.adc4gis.com/
I am making an AJAX call to send the file and get the response, but the response says "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"

Below is the code snippet for ajax call, where s File is the file from the file upload control. I tried to attach file in several methods for 'data' in ajax call (create `FormData` object, creating object etc), but I am getting the same error.

```
    function shapeFileProcessing(sFile){
           
         var formdata = new FormData();
         formdata.append("upload", sFile);
                   
         var obj = {};
         obj.upload = sFile;
                     
           $.ajax({
                  url : 'http://ogre.adc4gis.com/convert',
                  data : obj,
                  type : "POST",
                  success : function(msg) {
                    console.log("Success: "+msg);
                  }
          });
    }
```

And when I tried the same with Postman, this works (getting the converted file as response) [![enter image description here][1]][1])
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJO8T.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually appending your `formdata` to the AJAX request, but another object:

```
data : obj
```

Then what you also have to do is define this to prevent `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

The corrected function:

```
function shapeFileProcessing(sFile){

  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("upload", sFile);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://ogre.adc4gis.com/convert',
    data: formdata,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log("Success: "+msg);
    }
  });
}
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/x5YRc3ALEoiYWwThBqNa